# Split a Prolog predicate into two parts and execute some code in between

Tags: prolog

Let's say that I have an user that can write a Prolog predicate `pred/2` like this:

```
pred('an atom chosen by the user', OutputList) :-
  %Part 1
  %Here he can write every Prolog predicate that he wants
  %and before split_here he has to inizialize the OutputList
  ...

  split_here, %this is a special fact that that says where to split

  %Part 2
  %Here he can write every Prolog predicate that he wants
  ...
```

Then, I have some kind of engine that tries to execute this `pred/2` defined by the user, but for efficiency it needs to execute some code in between where `split_here` is declared (let's say a predicate `engine_code/0`).

How can I implement this pattern?

Variables in Part 1 and 2 could be shared whereas `engine_code/0` is only concerned about `OutputList` (it is not important what kind of terms it contains).

**Can you think of a simple way to accomplish this?**

For now, I am using `clause/2` like this:

```
clause(pred(X, OutputList), Body),
split(Body, split_here, Part1Goals, Part2Goals),
call(Part1Goals),
engine_code,
call(Part2Goals),
...
```

It seems that when I write `call(Part1Goals)` and `call(Part2Goals)` with `engine_code/0` in between or just in sequence the variables are not shared.

An example could be:

```
pred(userPred, OutputList) :-
  findall(myTerm(X,Y,Z), myTerm(X,Y,Z), OutputList),
  split_here,
  member(myTerm(X,_,_), OutputList),
  use_x(X).
```

Comment: How about performing the transformation you want when adding clauses to a dynamic predicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution is to use the goal-expansion mechanism to replace the `split_here` marker with the call to your `engine_code/0` predicate. The transformation would be accomplished when you load the user code. Term- and goal-expansion mechanism are available in some Prolog systems. For a portable solution working with most compiler systems you can use Logtalk's implementation of the mechanism. For example:

```
---- user.pl ----
pred(userPred, OutputList) :-
  findall(myTerm(X,Y,Z), myTerm(X,Y,Z), OutputList),
  split_here,
  member(myTerm(X,_,_), OutputList),
  use_x(X).
-----------------
```

The goal-expansion code:

```
---- hook.lgt ----
:- object(hook, implements(expanding)).

    goal_expansion(split_here, engine_code).

:- end_object.
-----------------
```

Example usage from the top-level. First, load the Prolog file expanding it with the `hook` object:

```
| ?- logtalk_load('user.pl', [hook(hook)]).
...
```

Second, simply call the transformed user predicate:

```
| ?- pred(userPred, OutputList).
...
```

Would this work for you?

Comment: For now I found a way to make mine work, but I like your idea as well. The necessity for the split_here predicate was due to the fact that I did not about this possibility. Thanks!